# Set POST parameter for WP ajax request that call from WP-CLI with do_action

Tags: wordpress, wp-cli

I need to call ajax request function from WP-CLI with POST parameters so my question is how can I set post params in do_action mention that I am calling from WP-CLI.

Example:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_publish_submit', 'publish_submit' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_publish_submit', 'publish_submit' );

function publish_submit() {
   $platform  = $_POST['platform'];
   $env       = $_POST['env'];
   ...      
}

// calling this ajax request from WP-CLI as below
wp eval "do_action('wp_ajax_publish_submit');"
```

I have tried with --args but did not worked. Also tried to set $_POST['platform'] but that also did not worked.

But not able to set `platform` and `env` post request params for do_action function that call ajax request function.